# Can you retrieve Amazon listing views / popularity from MWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve the number of views for each Amazon listing but I'm not having much luck so I'm wondering if this is actually possible?

I've seen the list of reports you can request here:

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html

But I can't see anything which would relate to listing views

I also found this thread

https://sellercentral-europe.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=111303&tstart=0

Which is asking for the same thing but says it's not possible

So it appears I'm not going to have much luck but I thought it was worth asking just in case there is anything that's not documented or anything new since that question was asked that could accomplish this?

If anyone is wondering why this information is required, we are looking to build a report within an ecommerce system to show the total views for certain date ranges to see the effect of any optimisations we make and track conversion rates etc

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well it doesn't look like this is currently possible

I've requested each listing report available and the field isn't in any of them

Putting the fields which are in each report here in case it helps someone seems I couldn't find this information anywhere online

Inventory Report (_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_)

sku asin    price   quantity

Active Listings Report (_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_)

item-name   item-description    listing-id  seller-sku  price   quantity    open-date   image-url   item-is-marketplace product-id-type zshop-shipping-fee  item-note   item-condition  zshop-category1 zshop-browse-path   zshop-storefront-feature    asin1   asin2   asin3   will-ship-internationally   expedited-shipping  zshop-boldface  product-id  bid-for-featured-placement  add-delete  pending-quantity    fulfillment-channel merchant-shipping-group

Open Listings Report (_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_BACK_COMPAT_)

item-name   item-description    listing-id  seller-sku  price   quantity    open-date   image-url   item-is-marketplace product-id-type zshop-shipping-fee  item-note   item-condition  zshop-category1 zshop-browse-path   zshop-storefront-feature    asin1   asin2   asin3   will-ship-internationally   expedited-shipping  zshop-boldface  product-id  bid-for-featured-placement  add-delete  pending-quantity    merchant-shipping-group

Open Listings Report Lite (_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_LITE_)

seller-sku  quantity    price   product-id

Open Listings Report Liter (_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_LITER_)

seller-sku  quantity

Canceled Listings Report (_GET_MERCHANT_CANCELLED_LISTINGS_DATA_)

item-name   item-description    seller-sku  price   quantity    image-url   item-is-marketplace product-id-type zshop-shipping-fee  item-note   item-condition  zshop-category1 zshop-browse-path   zshop-storefront-feature    asin1   asin2   asin3   will-ship-internationally   expedited-shipping  zshop-boldface  product-id  add-delete  merchant-shipping-group

Sold Listings Report (_GET_CONVERGED_FLAT_FILE_SOLD_LISTINGS_DATA_)

Couldn't fetch this one, kept getting a processing status of cancelled

Listing Quality and Suppressed Listing Report (_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DEFECT_DATA_)

sku product-name    asin    field-name  alert-type  current-value   last-updated    explanation